# Form submission without page refresh

Tags: html, php, ajax

I have a form and the details gets updated after submitting it and the page refreshes after that automatically and the details of the form will be shown at the bottom of the form. That means all the data from the database gets loaded below the form.

Is there a way to not to refresh the page but to show all the data from the database table even the latest one?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Since you have tagged this AJAX you seem to know that that is what you would use.   This is not a place to ask for help with coding though we will try to assist if something is not working and you can't figure out why.

Comment: i dont know how to work with ajax. can you point me out to the right place though :)

Comment: @GouseFeroz, google "ajax form submission" and go from there. There are plenty of good tutorials and also this https://goo.gl/FbDPLA stack overflow answer to steer you in the right direction. Consider asking further programming related questions in stack overflow (this is the webmaster.stackoverflow for webmaster questions).

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=ZMCqW5-GDtbr-QbWkIG4Cw&ins=false&q=how+to+update+a+web+page+with+ajax+after+submitting+a+form&oq=how+to+update+a+webpage+with+ajax+after+submitting+a+form&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-hp.1.0.30i10.2019.20019..22398...1.0..0.315.14747.2-53j4......0....1.......5..0j46j35i39j0i131j0i3j0i22i10i30j0i22i30j33i22i29i30j33i22i10i29i30j33i21j33i160j33i10i160j33i10i21.YcrPXVQcCV4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Steve](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/16250/steve)'s comment, I figured out that I can solve my problem using AJAX.